# Create an icon of Sage 6.4.1 in the panel of Ubuntu14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, icons, sagemath

I have install recently Sage6.4.1 in my Ubuntu14.04 LTS(32bit). Here is the screenshot of the installation process:

[image]

After installation the sage:
[image]

I want to create  an icon of Sage 6.4.1 in the panel of Ubuntu14.04 LTS like *Firefox* and others icon are there(above figure) from where I can easily open firefox etc.

The process is given here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SAGE.
But the process is complicated for me. Please tell me the easy way.
 Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On your desktop, right click and select new document, then edit it and insert:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=sage
Exec=gnome-terminal --command="/home/mks/Desktop/sage-6.4.1-i686-Linux/sage -notebook"
Icon=/home/mks/Desktop/sage-6.4.1-i686-Linux/local/share/sage/ext/images/sagelogo.png
Categories=Application;
```

Save the file (and traditionally name it sagenotebook.desktop.
Then just drag it onto the task bar.  (I hope I got your paths correct, check them just to be sure).